# How make `reverse-i-search` history use fzf in irb or pry console

Tags: irb, pry, fzf

I have looked around, can not find anyway to use [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) to search history in irb or pry console. Is there any way make it?

Answer (score 5):

After a look around, I get it that command completion is associated with [GNU Readline](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/readline/rdoc/Readline.html), and then I found a pure ruby implementation of [Readline](https://github.com/ConnorAtherton/rb-readline), in fact
It's quite easy to make fzf works in pry with `RbReadline`, what I have do is overwrite the `RbReadline`'s class method `rl_reverse_search_history`, which is triggered when we hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> in pry console.

Summary of what I have done:

1. Install rb-readline

   ```
    gem install rb-readline
   ```
2. Modify your `.pryrc` add this

   ```
    require 'rb-readline'

    def RbReadline.rl_reverse_search_history(sign, key)
      rl_insert_text  `cat ~/.pry_history | fzf --tac |  tr '\n' ' '`
    end
   ```

The `rl_insert_text` inserts the result you selected from fzf into the terminal after your cursor.